lightSlider carousel from Vertical to Horizontal
I am initializing a lightSlider carousel with "vertical:true" for Desktop and set a breakpoint at 900px with "vertical:false".
The problem is that the carousel does not change into the hozitontal position and stays into vertical, slides are going up and down instead of left and right.


Please do not post images of code. Instead may you replace it with a text-based [mcve]?
